# AWS Deployment with Rails - Inaccessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services

Could you tell me what happens with AWS Server now? From 3 weeks ago, util now, whenever I deploy my RoR app into AWS Server (using ElasticBeantalk tool), I meet a strange issue

Deployment time is quite good (just about 10-15 minutes), and the healthy of server is still green. But after that, the server is inaccessible. This status last about 3 - 4 hours !!! Then, everything is OK, server run fast and smoothly. I totally don't understand server healthy still un-change although this error happen. Everything I can do is "refresh browser periodically until it run"

I don't think my application is bigger enough with total deployment time like that. It just takes me about 20 minutes on local (production mode)

Here're some error I found out when server is hang:
"An error occured while starting up the preloader."

"Gateway timeout" when loading application.js (using chrome debug)

"Bad gateway" when loading application.js (using chrome debug)

Please give me some advise to solve that. I have been stucked on this issue for a long time
Thanks

Comment: You're running a server or instance? Can you give more info about your AWS environment?

Comment: Hello Rick,I dont understand your question clearly. But I can try:
I'm running a ec instance on my server. My AWS environment:
. Instance type: t1.micro

. Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling

. Add instance when > 6000000

. Remove instance when < 2000000


If you need any information, please tell me.
Thank for your responding